# remove the characters except <NIS/> ,<NONNATIVE/> and space

Tags: c#, regex

I have a huge amount of string data in a datatable, I want remove the characters except `<NIS/>`, `<NONNATIVE/>` and space. Example,

*before: `" There are<NONNATIVE/> not<NIS/> <NIS/> correct"`*

*after: `"  <NONNATIVE/> <NIS/> <NIS/> "`.*

Because the data is huge, I want find a fast method to handle it, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this I suppose

```
var before = " There are<NONNATIVE/> not<NIS/> <NIS/> correct";
var after = new StringBuilder();

Regex.Replace(before, @"( |<NONNATIVE\/>|<NIS\/>)", m =>
{
    after.Append(m.Value);
    return "";
});
```

It will catch those things you want to accept and add on a `StringBuilder`, then you just have to convert it `ToString`

```
//   <NONNATIVE/> <NIS/> <NIS/> 
after.ToString();
```

Comment: Thanks! This method cost 0.0005s per data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following.

```
string input  = " There are<NONNATIVE/> not<NIS/> <NIS/> correct";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"((?> |<NIS\/>|<NONNATIVE\/>)*)\S?", "$1");

// "  <NONNATIVE/> <NIS/> <NIS/> "
```

See [`Live demo`](http://regex101.com/r/qA0xS0)

Comment: Thanks very much,this way cost me 0.0001s per data!!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about performance but this will also work:

```
string input1 = " There are<NONNATIVE/> not<NIS/> <NIS/> correct";
string[] approvedlist = {"<NONNATIVE/>","<NIS/>"};
string output1 = string.Join(" ", (from s in input1.Split(@"<>".ToCharArray())
                                           where approvedlist.Contains(s)
                                           select "<" + s + ">").ToArray());
```

I did a performance test and this is almost equal to Bruno's example on over 100000 characters with the strings you want randomly inserted every 5- 20 characters.

Did some optimizing and took into account your further comments and came up with this:

```
        string[] approvedlist = {"<NONNATIVE/>","<NIS/>"};
        var output2 = new StringBuilder();
        foreach(string s in input1.Split(@"<>".ToCharArray()))
            if(approvedlist.Contains(s))
                output2.AppendFormat("<{0}> ", s);
```

In my tests this outperformed everything else thus far.

Comment: Thanks!may be linq cost a lot,this way cost me 0.03s per data.

Comment: One thing I noticed between this method and the regex methods.  This puts spaces between every element that you want returned.  Whereas the regex only have spaces between some of them.  I'd also like to see how you're testing this I get quite different results.

Comment: My test string is not as long as you used,and there are also some other tag like "<UNKNOW/>",those also should remove.

Comment: You will probably need a bigger test string to get truer results.  I did some more thinking and was able to optimize my code even further and restricted the output to just the tags you wanted.